# Fetch Stats using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I am using this page: http://www.afl.com.au/match-centre/2014/20/rich-v-esshttp://www.afl.com.au/match-centre/2014/19/fre-v-carl

to fetch the stats which is given at right hand side. I have attached a screen shot below.

[image]

I have used the following function to fetch the data. I have created the soup and passed it as a parameter to the below function

```
def fetchStats(soup):

    for i in soup.findAll("div", {"class" : "module", "id" : "season-stats"}):
        for index in i.findAll("div", {"class" : "module-content"}):
            for item in index.findAll("ul", style=False):

                li = item.findAll("li", {"class" : "major"})
                 print item.getText()
            break
        break
```

But it is not working as I want. I need all the parameters for a team to be stored in a dictionary where in the key of the dictionary would be the team name and its value would have tuple having two members - parameter name and its value, like,

```
dic = {"Team 1 Name": [("Disposlas",311), ("Kicks", 190) .....], "Team 2 Name" : [("Disposlas",315), ("Kicks", 224) .....]}
```

Please help me out.

Comment: You should probably post the HTML.

Comment: Looking at the link, they are 3 unordered lists (UL element). I would get all three into arrays, then combine them into one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to get all of the home team stats, away team stats and stats names and put them into separate lists, then [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) them:

```
from pprint import pprint
from urllib2 import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "http://www.afl.com.au/match-centre/2014/20/rich-v-esshttp://www.afl.com.au/match-centre/2014/19/fre-v-carl"
soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url))

# get team names
home_team_name = soup.find('div', class_='home-team').p.a.text.strip()
away_team_name = soup.find('div', class_='away-team').p.a.text.strip()

# get stats
season_stats = soup.find('div', id='season-stats')
home_stats = [li.text for li in season_stats.select('ul#home-team-stats > li')]
away_stats = [li.text for li in season_stats.select('ul#away-team-stats > li')]
params = [li.text for li in season_stats.select('ul.headers > li')]

stats = {home_team_name: zip(params, home_stats),
         away_team_name: zip(params, away_stats)}

pprint(stats)
```

Prints:

```
{u'Carlton': [(u'Disposals', u'315'),
              (u'Kicks', u'224'),
              (u'Handballs', u'91'),
              (u'Free Kicks', u'22'),
              (u'Clearances', u'39'),
              (u'Centre', u'13'),
              (u'Stoppages', u'26'),
              (u'Inside 50', u'40'),
              (u'Marks in 50', u'8'),
              (u'Contested Possessions', u'127'),
              (u'Tackles', u'59'),
              (u'Hit-Outs', u'23'),
              (u'Interchanges', u'111')],
 u'Fremantle': [(u'Disposals', u'311'),
                (u'Kicks', u'190'),
                (u'Handballs', u'121'),
                (u'Free Kicks', u'14'),
                (u'Clearances', u'38'),
                (u'Centre', u'10'),
                (u'Stoppages', u'28'),
                (u'Inside 50', u'47'),
                (u'Marks in 50', u'13'),
                (u'Contested Possessions', u'124'),
                (u'Tackles', u'63'),
                (u'Hit-Outs', u'75'),
                (u'Interchanges', u'96')]}
```

FYI, you can read more about these `select()` calls here: [`CSS Selectors`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors).

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, it is so helpful. And also I learnt ways to use bs4. Thanks again

Comment: @Anand and I enjoyed writing it, thanks for an interesting task :)

Comment: @Anand thanks, make sure you understand everything in the code please. Otherwise it wouldn't be really helpful. Ask, in case you have questions about the code.

Comment: Sir, speaking honestly I could understand but 90% of the code you gave me. I need time and want to study `zip`. I will study it well and write here if I have problems. You used `ul#home-team-stats > li` , I will have to study this too